# How to derive Dirac's quantization of electric and magnetic charge from Berry's phase?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-monopoles, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I have seen two ways of deriving Dirac's quantization of electric and magnetic charge using Berry's phase, one from Sakurai's book *Modern Quantum Mechanics* P354~355 and the other from David Tong's note [solid1](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/aqm/solid1.pdf). However, I don't understand both of the derivations.

---

In Sakurai's book, he first gives the quantization condition for Berry's phase
$$
\oint \boldsymbol{B}\cdot d\boldsymbol{a} = 2N\pi , \quad(5.6.47)
$$
and says that the Berry field of a spin-1/2 particle in a rotating magnetic field, i.e.
$$
\boldsymbol{B}_{\pm}(\boldsymbol{R}) = \mp \frac{1}{2R^2(t)} \hat{\boldsymbol{R}} , \quad(5.6.41)
$$
looks suspiciously like the magnetic field from a monopole.
Then he says

> but recall that it is in fact a Berry field. How can we relate this to
> an actual magnetic field for a monopole? It is actually easiest to see
> this when we express Berry's Phase in terms of the line integral in
> (5.6.24) of the vector potential around the curve $C$. The gauge
> transformation (2.7.83) gives the form of the vector potential, and
> the line integral is just an integral over $\phi$ leading to a factor of
> $2\pi$. We can then use this to evaluate the left side of (5.6.47),
> including the interaction with a single electric charge $e$ to complete
> the phase, leading to the factor $e/\hbar c$ as in (2.7.84). Thus, (5.6.47)
> becomes
> $$
> \frac{e}{\hbar c}(2e_M)2\pi = 2N\pi .
> $$

(2.7.83) is the gauge transformation that T.T.Wu and C.N.Yang used to derive Dirac's quantization, i.e.
$$
\Lambda = -2e_M \phi .
$$
I don't understand how to "including the interaction ......". To my understanding, the gauge transformation that corresponds to the Berry curvature is just
$$
\Lambda = \mp\phi ,
$$
in which no $e$ or $e_M$ is included. I hope someone could give me some formulae to explain this paragraph.

---

In David Tong's note, he deduces Dirac's quantization using the Berry's phase of the AB effect. But to my understanding, this AB phase only works in the region where $\boldsymbol{B}=0$, which is not satisfied by the magnetic field of a monopole. So how can this derivation be correct?